# C# Log file entries, DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I'm dealing with a log journal (CSV file) which is created by some equipment (Heat Pump). My app should upload these historical csv files to SQL database and then do some analysis. The journal has many timestamped entries which are generated every minute or more depends on settings. The issue is regarding DST  (Daylight saving time). The equipment is smart enough to know about DST, so on the day of DST transition in Autumn I have duplicated (by DateTime column) entries in the journal because the clock of hardware corrects itself according to DST rules.

Example:

```
2014-10-26  02:00:12    ....................
2014-10-26  02:01:12    ....................
....<other records>..............................................
2014-10-26  02:59:12    ....................
2014-10-26  02:00:12    ....................
2014-10-26  02:01:09    ....................
2014-10-26  02:02:09    ....................
2014-10-26  02:03:09    ....................
```

So to have true DateTime value I want to convert DateTime to UTC or at least eliminate DST impact. Now I'm thinking what would be the easiest way to identify which entry with duplicated timestamp belongs to which time period: before the moment of DST transition or after. The task is even more complicated because the journal may be corrupted so I cant simply compare two value from adjacent records and make decision. And I can't ignore that because this will lead to problems later on when I start to calculate time differences for analysis. Also it won't let me upload to SQL table as I want a DateTime column to be an index key.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Show us the code you have made so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Set the heat pump to UTC and run it all in that time zone.